# Getting syntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, html

Write a function named "plotLine" that takes an array of points where each element is an array in the format [x, y] and both x and y are floating points Numbers. The function will create a line chart in a div with id of "plot" using the Plotly library. You may assume that your code runs on a page where Plotly is downloaded.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"
></script>
<script
function plotLine(array){
    var object1 =
    {
        "data":
        [{
            "x": array.map(i => i[0]),
            "y": array.map(i => i[1])
        }]
    };
    return object1;
}
></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="plot"></div>
<script src="plots.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting syntaxError: Unexpected token <. What am I doin wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to wrap your javascript in `<script>function plotLine()...</script>` tags?

Comment: you did not enclose your JS code in `<script>...</script>`

Comment: put your code into script tag <script>your code...</script>

Comment: I am still getting  SyntaxError: Unexpected token < after doing what is told.

Comment: This is a typographical error. Close your tags correctly. `<script>//your code here</script>`. Also, please accept answers to your other questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
function plotLine(array){
    var object1 =
    {
        "data":
        [{
            "x": array.map(i => i[0]),
            "y": array.map(i => i[1])
        }]
    };
    return object1;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="plot"></div>
<script src="plots.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error when using your code.

Comment: @Anonymous And now? If this still doesn't work, the problem is most likely inside your scrup plot.js.

Comment: plots.js is fine. That is what I am supposed to be using.

Comment: Well, the rest is valid HTML. You are missing a doctype and a title attribute, but that's it. Your JS is somewhere else, either in plotly or in plots.js.

Comment: @Anonymous, this code runs fine for me too. If you want better help, you need to post code that reproduces the problem you're having.

Comment: I am receiving error on input [[[1.22, -1.43], [-5.47, -0.51], [-6.54, 7.29]]]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Again, your error is somewhere else. In one of the scripts. We can't help if we don't see that code and that input. Add that to your main post.